# How to deploy NX expressJS build project

Tags: express, netlify, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nomachine-nx

My server not able to read main.js. in netlify

```
- dist
-- apps
--- expressAPI
---- assets
---- main.js
---- main.js.map
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to [generatePackageJson](https://nx.dev/packages/node/executors/webpack#generatepackagejson) on build.

1. open file `apps/expressAPI/project.json`
2. find build options at `targets -> build -> options`
3. add new option `"generatePackageJson": true`
4. run build for `expressAPI`

after that you'll see a `package.json` file with required dependencies in the dist folder