# Express app from NX monorepo deployment using Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, monorepo

I have an NX monorepo with a React and an Express app. I managed to deploy my React app to Netlify but I have no idea how to deploy the API. I tried to do it the same way as I did for the React app but I always get an error screen. By the way, the express app shouldn't necessarily be deployed to heroku, I would like to find the easiest way. So can someone help me with how to deploy it and which platform should I choose for free?

Comment: Here is the link for the repo: https://github.com/ZsombiTech/junction

Comment: you need to update api project config to generate package.json on build. see more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74457379/1142300